# Did not device token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am a newbie to IOS development and testing push notification. I followed all steps for notification service referring this site:

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Of course, I have certificate and profile for notification and set project property as well.

And I put code in AppDelegate.m to get device token;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    DebugLog(@"************* devToken=%@",deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    DebugLog(@"************* Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}
```

I
But nothing is happening. I think it should return error or device token but I cannot any relating log in the console. I don't have any idea about this issue. How can I fixe this?

EDIT:
I have found the cause. I did not set notification service for the app in the settings. It works now after doing it. Do I need to turn on the setting always by manual?

Comment: If you add breakpoints in the application:did[FailTo]RegisterForRemoteNotificationsWith[DeviceToken|Error]: selectors, are they hit? Is it possible that your call to `DebugLog` isn't logging anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your app's notification may be disabled in device settings.
In order to enable this

Go to **Settings->Notifications->YourApp->Enable_Notifications**

One more thing, if your device doesnt have **network connection**, this delegates wont invoke.

Comment: Thanks, it feels annoying to me, familiar with Android. How can I turn it on automatically?

Comment: it will ask automatically for allowing push notification after registering your remote notification. Did ur problem solved now?

Comment: did you get any pop-up regarding push notification use first time when u run the app.. and if you are not getting Token then there problem with .ck refer [Here] (http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/)